# Python String Encoding that uses &#x**;

Tags: python, html

I have one (non-python) script that encodes a string a certain way, and I need a python script to use the same method of encoding.

The original string is `Hügelkultur` and the original script converts that to `H&#xFC;gelkultur`.

Right now my python script isn't doing any type of encoding and the output file shows `HÃ¼gelkultur`.

If I run this script:

```
string = "Hügelkultur"
string = string.encode()
print(string)
```

It outputs `H\xc3\xbcgelkultur`.

How would I want to encode the string to give me one that matches the original?

Comment: Those are (hex) HTML entities. You're looking for an HTML encoder.

Comment: do you happen to know which encoding you're using in your original script?

Comment: It might be tricky to get *exactly* that, since there are multiple entities that could refer to the same Unicode character. `ü`, for example, could be `&uuml;` or `&#xFC;`. Whether you *need* an entity depends on the encoding of your file; as long as you can produce a UTF-8 encoded file, you can simply specify `ü` as the bytes `\xc3\xbc` directly instead of an entity.

Comment: @adiaz004,  I don't. There's a script that runs and generates some static files. I need to make my output match with that one.

Comment: I got close with `string = string.encode(encoding="ascii",errors="xmlcharrefreplace")` but the output is decimal whereas I need it to be in hex. `&#252;` vs `&#xFC;`.

Comment: Why does it need to be *exactly* the same? Are you trying to do a byte-wise comparison of the two files?

Comment: The two outputs are matched against each other to create a nodes and edges in a webgraph. If they're not the same then they are considered different nodes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not aware of a stdlib encoder to get that output, but an ascii encoding with an xmlcharrefreplace will get you most of the way there:

```
>>> "Hügelkultur".encode("ascii", errors="xmlcharrefreplace")
b'H&#252;gelkultur'
```

The `#xFC` is like `#252` because `0xfc == 252`, and HTML decoders should be happy with either form. However, if you do need an *exact* style match, perhaps just write a simple function to do this manually:

```
>>> def convert(s):
...     chars = []
...     for char in s:
...         if char.isascii():
...             chars.append(char)
...         else:
...             chars.append(f"&#x{ord(c):X};")
...     return "".join(chars)
...
>>> convert("Hügelkultur")
'H&#xFC;gelkultur'
```

For posterity's sake, going back the other way is an html unescape:

```
>>> import html
>>> html.unescape('H&#xFC;gelkultur')
'Hügelkultur'
```